# Load content select option from another page

Tags: jquery, ajax

don't change , i want Default show selected `<option value = "content1" selected> content1 </ option>`
Please see [**my code**](https://jsfiddle.net/n65b9rcq/)

```
<select id="select123">
<option value="content1">content1</option>
<option value="content2">content2</option>
<option value="content3">content3</option>
<option value="content4">content4</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
<img src="loading.gif" id="loadingImage" style="display: none;" />
```

my-page.php
//my-page.php

```
<div id="content1" class="content123">text defult show</div>
<div id="content2" class="content123">contentttttttt</div>
<div id="content3" class="content123">content3</div>
<div id="content4" class="content123">content4</div>
```

my jQuery (ajax) code [**in jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n65b9rcq/)

```
    jQuery(function($) { 
    jQuery('#select123').change(function() { 
    jQuery("#loadingImage").show(); 
       jQuery.ajax({ method: "POST",
     url: "my-page.php",
     data: { workselected1: jQuery(this).val() },
     success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
     jQuery("#loadingImage").hide();
 }); }); });
```

Comment: Not at all clear what the specific problem is here. Please provide a more specific problem statement

Comment: I want to display the contents of my-page.php in #content

Answer (score 0):

I hope that one of the professors will help `$.ajax OR .load() OR .post()`